# Highest Since when?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have the dataframe below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily']
years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(5, 25))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=names, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, months]))
```

I get names as rows and dates as columns and random numbers as values. What I am trying to do is create a column at the end that tells me the last time the value for the last column (May 2023) was higher than it was in May 2023. In other words, highest since when? I tried some functions that I thought would itterate backwards through the rows until a value was higher but nothing has worked.

I tried this:

```
cols=df.columns.tolist()
def highest_since(row):
    z=-1
    if df[cols[-1]]>df[cols[z-1]]==True:
        z=z-1
    else:
        return df[cols[z]]

df['highest_since']=df[cols[-1]].apply(highest_since)
```

I get an error.

This would be useful when looking at stock prices to see last time a stock price was higher.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily']
years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(5, 25))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=names, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, months]))

def highest_since(row):
    cols = row.index  
    z = -2
    while z >= -len(cols):
        if row[cols[-1]] > row[cols[z]]:
            return cols[z]
        z -= 1
    return None 

df['highest_since'] = df.apply(highest_since, axis=1)
print(df)
```

which gives

```
        2019                 2020                  ... 2022             2023  \
         Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May  ...  Feb Mar Apr May  Jan   
Alice     53  54  55  14  42   78  49  47  62  71  ...   16  61  83  56   14   
Bob       44   6  84  36  68   35  41  89  67   2  ...   32  11  86  12   24   
Charlie   77  75  25  26  56   90  89   7  89   5  ...   79  22  20  32   28   
David     62   2  39  60  93   31  63  37   5  53  ...    8  16  79   8   53   
Emily     62  41   9  36  34   66  50  43  45   4  ...    7  27  17  10   27   

                        highest_since  
        Feb Mar Apr May                
Alice    57  48  43  17   (2023, Jan)  
Bob      80  90  95   7   (2020, May)  
Charlie  94  93  75  89   (2023, Apr)  
David    96  27  38  96   (2023, Apr)  
Emily    81  94  43  99   (2023, Apr)  

[5 rows x 26 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some string manipulations and matrix multiplication:

```
# Flat MultiIndex and get a string representaton: (2019, Jan) -> 'Jan 2019'
cols = pd.Index([f'{m} {y},' for y, m in df.columns[:-1]])

# Get a boolean mask (True, False) and use dot multiplication
# to select columns where columns >= last column (May 2023)
df['highest_since'] = (df.iloc[:, :-1].ge(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0).dot(cols)
                         .str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').str[-1])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        2019                 2020                 2021                 2022                 2023                 highest_since
         Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May              
Alice     41  72  37  91  95   48  57  78  16  80    1  96  40  80  98   73   2  45  28  75   43  57   1   7  63      May 2022
Bob        6  38  78  76  96   21  68  21  13  45   58  71  48  20  98   19   4  90  11  86   15  88  59  30  78      Feb 2023
Charlie   99  49   4  88  91   71  46  36  20  12   46  61  65  30  45   42  28  95  37  85    6   8  36  89  48      Apr 2023
David     98  84  89  91  98   77  84  52  40  26   60  13  15  94  72   18  83  74  85  92   61  15  29  24  27      Mar 2023
Emily     10  11  51  57  27   28  39   8  87  48   77  53  86  96  96   41  70  24  16  97   78  17  26  22  32      Jan 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the most straightforward if to use an [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on the boolean array comparing the last value to all:

```
df['highest_since'] = df.iloc[:, ::-1].gt(df.iloc[:,-1], axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        2019                 2020                  ... 2022             2023  \
         Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May  ...  Feb Mar Apr May  Jan   
Alice     45  48  65  68  68   10  84  22  37  88  ...   40  88  47  89   82   
Bob       10  21  81  70  80   48  65  83  89  50  ...   66  10  58  33   32   
Charlie   56  29  35   1   1   37  54   6  39  18  ...   66  42  58  36   12   
David     15  54  13  43  85   76  69   7  69  48  ...   59  24  80  14   86   
Emily     36  65  96  70  95    1  51  37  35  49  ...   74   1  11  44   59   

                        highest_since  
        Feb Mar Apr May                
Alice    38  26  78  73   (2023, Apr)  
Bob      75  24  36  76   (2020, Apr)  
Charlie  47  83  92   1   (2023, Apr)  
David    49  50  70  42   (2023, Apr)  
Emily    24  60   3  99   (2023, May)  

[5 rows x 26 columns]
```

If you want to have `NaN` is there never was a higher value before:

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, ::-1].gt(df.iloc[:,-1], axis=0)
df['highest_since'] = df2.idxmax(axis=1).where(df2.any(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
        2019                 2020                  ... 2022             2023  \
         Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May  ...  Feb Mar Apr May  Jan   
Alice     45  48  65  68  68   10  84  22  37  88  ...   40  88  47  89   82   
Bob       10  21  81  70  80   48  65  83  89  50  ...   66  10  58  33   32   
Charlie   56  29  35   1   1   37  54   6  39  18  ...   66  42  58  36   12   
David     15  54  13  43  85   76  69   7  69  48  ...   59  24  80  14   86   
Emily     36  65  96  70  95    1  51  37  35  49  ...   74   1  11  44   59   

                        highest_since  
        Feb Mar Apr May                
Alice    38  26  78  73   (2023, Apr)  
Bob      75  24  36  76   (2020, Apr)  
Charlie  47  83  92   1   (2023, Apr)  
David    49  50  70  42   (2023, Apr)  
Emily    24  60   3  99           NaN  # there was never a value > 99

[5 rows x 26 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

let's see the code and I explain below how to interpret

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily']
years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(5, 25))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=names, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, months]))

r1 = df.stack()
k = pd.concat([r1.iloc[:,4:]]).reset_index().drop_duplicates(['level_0'],keep='last')

def func(g, rfy=2023):
    name = g.index[0][0]
    v = k[rfy][k['level_0'].eq(name)].values[0]
    return g.applymap(lambda x: v)

mask = r1.gt(r1.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g:func(g)))

cmp = (r1[mask].dropna(axis=0, how='all')
               .reset_index())

cmp['level_1'] = pd.to_datetime(cmp['level_1'], format='%b')

cmp = (pd.melt(cmp, id_vars=['level_0','level_1'])
         .sort_values(by=['level_0','variable', 'level_1'])
         .dropna(axis=0)
         .drop_duplicates(['level_0'],keep='last')
         )

cmp['level_1'] = cmp['level_1'].dt.strftime('%b')

cmp.set_axis(['Name', 'Prv hghst mnth', 'Prv hghst year', 'Prv hghst Value'], axis=1,inplace=True)

print(cmp)
```

```
       Name Prv hghst mnth Prv hghst year  Prv hghst Value
55    Alice            Mar           2022             90.0
76      Bob            Jan           2023             64.0
61  Charlie            Apr           2022             88.0
83    David            Apr           2023             61.0
88    Emily            Jan           2023             80.0
```

**Checkings**

Like df is randomized I put here my df :

```
        2019                 2020          ... 2022         2023                
         Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar  ...  Mar Apr May  Jan Feb Mar Apr May
Alice     63  25  18  68  62   74  76  10  ...   90  15  56   52  30  41  69  88
Bob       21  54  97  10  41   10   8  96  ...   17  23  37   64  10  50  17  50
Charlie   98  89  71  94  22   41  57   1  ...   89  88  25   10  34  74  73  75
David     60  12  73  52  28   61  22  41  ...   77  21  35   30  84  39  61  57
Emily     43  23  59  49  53   90   2  35  ...   87  88  15   80  36  35  56  63

[5 rows x 25 columns]
```